# Automapper v5.1.1 - Circular references

Tags: c#, automapper-5

I know this might be flagged as a duplicate question, and yes, I did review the *questions that may already have answered my question*, but still couldn't find an answer.

As most of the other questions relate to, my issue is related to models that reference each other. I am well aware of other approaches that I can follow, like refactoring my code to create separate DTO objects for the children. Problem is, there are quite allot of models and refactoring everything will be very cumbersome.

I read the Automapper [v5.0 Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide), which states the following:

[image]

Which I've tried - for example the `ClientModel`:

```
var clientModelMap = CreateMap<Client, ClientModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, source => source.MapFrom(x => x.ClientId))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.InvoicePayments, source => source.Ignore());

clientModelMap.MaxDepth(1);
clientModelMap.PreserveReferences();
```

as well as in the `Project` model:

```
var projectModelMap = CreateMap<Project, ProjectModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Client, source => source.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, source => source.MapFrom(x => x.ProjectId))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ClientName, source => source.MapFrom(x => x.Client.ClientName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ClientTariff, source => source.MapFrom(x => x.Client.Tariff))
    ;
projectModelMap.MaxDepth(1);
projectModelMap.PreserveReferences();
```

The structure is as follows:

- Client

  - Project (each client has many projects)

    - Resource (each project has a project manager)

      - Projects (is associated with one or more projects he/she is working on)
      - Client (is associated with a client / acts as the manager)

But this has no effect, and I still receive a `StackOverflowException`. What am I missing or doing wrong?

I'm open for suggestions, if this is not the way to go.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you set up a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @stuartd - thanks for the response. I actually found my issue. The code examples provided by the v5.0 Guide functions correctly. The thing is I didn't implement it futher down in the model hierarchy.

Comment: Just to better understand `MaxDepth(x)`: it basically states the following. For each time it enters the mapping profile for the specified model being mapped, it will check whether the max has been reached. Thus if you could like a `Client` to reference a `Project` as well as a `User`, then you set it to 2. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

It's functioning as expected - I just needed to update mapping profiles on the rest of the model hierarchy.